# Departure immigration formalities

Tags: customs-and-immigration

I’m an USA passport holder and departing Bangalore airport via Bombay. Where do I complete immigration formalities?

Comment: Can you please edit in which airports in which order? I am a bit confused about what you mean.

Comment: Bangalore seems the obvious answer, since that’s your departure point. Do you have a reason to think otherwise? Or is your question about immigration at your final destination, which you don’t mention?

Comment: @Traveller OP probably means exit passport checks rather than check-in. Exit passport checks usually happen at the last airport before leaving the country, but I believe India have a few internal flights designed for international connections where you would do the exit passport control at the point of origin.

Comment: Could you clarify the flight numbers involved?

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you are travelling from Bengaluru to the US via Mumbai but that's hard to tell from your question.

The most likely order of events is:

1. For check-in (online or in Bengaluru) you need to present your US passport
2. Bengaluru to Mumbai is a domestic flight. No immigration involved but you still need a document for ID verification.
3. You will go through Indian exit immigration in Mumbai
4. You will go through US entry immigration in your first port of entry in the US
5. Any subsequent travel within the US does not involve immigration at all.

Comment: Air India used to have domestic legs which were considered as international but it’s apparently no longer the case. Getting the actual flight numbers may help.